# Is there an URL parameter to modify the volume of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, url

I want to put a link to a YouTube video on my website, but the sound is super loud. Is there a way to reduce the volume by adding some kind of parameter to the link? The way you can append `&t=1m` at the end of it and it automatically starts at the 1 minute mark? (By the way, I'm not talking about the embedding code.)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no parameter to control video volume.

Full list of available parameters can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters). You mentioned, that you don't want to embed a player, but URL can be used basically the same as the value of `src` element.

Answer (score 1):

No, as stated  before but there is a javascript answer for it, see [player.setVolume(Number)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#setVolume) from the YouTube Javascript API page.